# jQuery - how can I select html5 custom attribute which is equal something

Tags: jquery, html, select, custom-attributes

If I have this:

```
<span data-helo="1">something</span>
<span data-helo="2">something different</span>
```

and I want to target the first span, how should I do it?

I tried something like:

```
$('span').data('helo', '1')
```

But it returned both spans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$('span[data-helo="1"]')
```

this will target all `span`-elements with a `data-helo`-attribute of value `1`.

http://jsfiddle.net/F2NUk/

with your code:

```
$('span').data('helo', '1')
```

you're targeting all `span`-elements and setting their `data-helo` attribute to `1`. And then returning that collection (through typical jQuery chaining).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/FNmFb/1/)**

**For Assignment**

```
$('span').attr('data-helo', '2');
```

**For selection**

```
$('span[data-helo=2]')
```

​

Answer (score 1):

you can try `eq()` and `data()` method:

```
$('span:eq(0)').data('helo'); // returns "1"
$('span:eq(1)').data('helo'); // returns "2"
```

if you want to select element by the attribute, you can use attribute selector:

```
$('span[data-helo="1"]') // selects spans which has attribute "data-helo" and it's value is "1" 
$('span[data-helo="2"]')
```

or:

```
$('span[data-helo]:eq(0)') // first span element that has a data-helo attribute
$('span[data-helo]:eq(1)') // second span element that has a data-helo attribute
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

I think it is what you want

```
 $('span[data-helo=1]')
```